# Trying to change the cloumn type in hive, running a DDL, but it's throwing an error "

Tags: hadoop, hive, ddl, hive-serde

Trying to change the cloumn type  in hive, running a DDL, but it's throwing an error

Running the following DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE INV.HTL_RATE_PLAN
CHANGE RATE_PLAN_RSTRCT_STRT_DT RATE_PLAN_RSTRCT_STRT_DT DATE 
COMMENT 'Advance booking alternate days restriction rule applied to a rate category. This rule dictates the minimum number of days before arrival the guest must book for the rate category to be available.'
AFTER PRICE_GRID_CD;
```

Error:

```
Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Reordering columns is not supported for table INV_TRF.HTL_RATE_PLAN. SerDe may be incompatible.
```

Help? What am I doing Wrong. Please Suggest.

Answer (score 1):

To change column type, you need just for this :

```
ALTER TABLE INV.HTL_RATE_PLAN
CHANGE RATE_PLAN_RSTRCT_STRT_DT RATE_PLAN_RSTRCT_STRT_DT DATE 
COMMENT 'Advance booking alternate days restriction rule applied to a rate category. This rule dictates the minimum number of days before arrival the guest must book for the rate category to be available.';
```

Th removed part `AFTER PRICE_GRID_CD` change the column position to be after the specified column, but your storage type which is handled by the serde, does not support this operation.